# Bar Plot with recent dates left where date is datetime index

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, datetimeindex

I tried to sort the dataframe by datetime index and then plot the graph but no change still it was showing where latest dates like 2017, 2018 were in right and 2008, 2009 were left.

[image]

I wanted the latest year to come left and old to the right.
This was the dataframe earlier.

```
            Title  
Date                      
2001-01-01      0       
2002-01-01      9        
2003-01-01     11       
2004-01-01     17       
2005-01-01     23       
2006-01-01     25       
2007-01-01     51       
2008-01-01     55       
2009-01-01    120      
2010-01-01    101     
2011-01-01     95       
2012-01-01    118      
2013-01-01     75       
2014-01-01     75       
2015-01-01     3      
2016-01-01     35       
2017-01-01     75       
2018-01-01     55
```

Ignore the values.
Then I sort the above dataframe by index, and then plot but still no change in plots

```
df.sort_index(ascending=False, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas plot x or index\_column in descending order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29511645/pandas-plot-x-or-index-column-in-descending-order)

Comment: Your data structure is not clear, because you have not provided a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). How you arrived from your data table to the posted picture remains a mystery - the numbers don't match at all. So the question is also unclear, why your sorting didn't affect the plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `invert_xaxis()`:

```
df.plot.bar().invert_xaxis()
```

If you don't want to use Pandas plotting:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.bar(df.index, df['Title'])
ax.invert_xaxis()
```

Comment: I am plotting using ax, so following one is giving error,
ax.bar(df1.index, df1['Title'], width=100, zorder=3).invert_xaxis()

Answer (score 0):

I guess you've not change your index to year. This is why it is not working.you can do so by:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.Date).dt.year
#then sort index in descending order
df.sort_index(ascending = False , inplace = True)
df.plot.bar()
```